# Оповещения Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Недавно начал изучать Bootstrap и столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно сделать оповещения (алертом), как в вконтакте, которое сообщало бы о том или ином действии.
Есть ли такое в Bootstrap, и где это можно найти?

Comment: @Ololoevv, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скажу вам по секрету, что все что там есть, описано на страницах CSS, Components, JavaScript на [официальном сайте](http://getbootstrap.com/)

[Стандартный алерт](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) вполне можно спозиционировать как вам нужно и [добавить крестик](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)

UPD. А еще есть такая штука: http://notifyjs.com/

Comment: в том и проблема...
что тут оно фиксированное на странице...

видел недавно сайт, у него сверху строка была как оповещения...

Comment: @Ololoevv что вам мешает дописать немного CSS и спозиционировать, как требуется вам?

Comment: большое спасибо, то, что я искал...